# translate Dataframe using crosswalk in julia

Tags: dataframe, join, julia, translate, crosswalk

I have a very large dataframe (original_df) with columns of codes

```
14 15
21 22
18 16
```

And a second dataframe (crosswalk) which maps 'old_codes' to 'new_codes'

```
14 104
15 105
16 106
18 108
21 201
22 202
```

Of course, the resultant df (resultant_df) that I would like would have values:

```
104 105
201 202
108 106
```

I am aware of two ways to accomplish this. First, I could iterate through each code in original_df, find the code in crosswalk, then rewrite the corresponding cell in original_df with the translated code from crosswalk. The faster and more natural option would be to leftjoin() each column of original_df on 'old_codes'. Unfortunately, it seems I have to do this separately for each column, and then delete each column after its conversion column has been created -- this feels unnecessarily complicated. Is there a simpler way to convert all of original_df at once using the crosswalk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following (I am using column numbers as you have not provided column names):

```
d = Dict(crosswalk[!, 1] .=> crosswalk[!, 2])
resultant_df = select(original_df, [i => ByRow(x -> d[x]) for i in 1:ncol(original_df)], renamecols=false)
```

Comment: Wonderful! Is there any way to add conditionals on ByRow()? I tried `ByRow(x -> d[x] if x in keys(d))` which didn't seem to work. More generally, a way to learn about ByRow? Happy to make this it's own post if you'd prefer.

Comment: I asked ByRow to act on a function which included the conditional in it, for now. Not sure how this impacts speed, but it works.

Comment: `ByRow(fun)` is just `x -> fun.(x)`. You mean condition to filter-out some rows?. Then it is best to do this before doing select e.g. by indexing or using `filter`. And yes - please ask a separate question to expand on some issue that is not clear and I will answer. Using a condition in `ByRow` is not a problem. The hard thing would be if you wanted to filter out some rows.